# Is there an equivalent of the Harvard sentences for Brazillian Portuguese?

Tags: português-brasileiro, fonologia, fonética

The Harvard sentences ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_sentences), [full list of sentences](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ehgs/audio/harvard.html)) are a set of English sentences that:

1. Are phonetically balanced in the sense that the phonemes that are used in the sentences appear at the same frequency they do in English.
2. Contain all phonemes that appear in English.

Here are a few examples of them:

1. Oak is strong and also gives shade.
2. Cats and dogs each hate the other.
3. The pipe began to rust while new.
4. Open the crate but don't break the glass.

**Question:** Is there an equivalent of the Harvard sentences for Brazilian Portuguese, i.e. a phonetically balanced collection of Brazilian Portuguese sentences containing all phonemes used in Brazilian Portuguese?

---

Worthy of mention are the [CAPE-V](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/7533012/mod_folder/content/0/Fona%C3%A7%C3%A3o%202021/Artigos%20e%20livros/Artigos%20e%20livros/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20vocal/CAPE%20-V%20REFLETINDO%20SOBRE%20O%20NOVO%20-%20REVISTA%20SBFa.pdf) sentences:

1. Érica tomou suco de pêra e amora.
2. Sonia sabe sambar sozinha.
3. Olha lá o avião azul.
4. Agora é hora de acabar.
5. Minha mãe namorou um anjo
6. Papai trouxe pipoca quente

They were designed to test specific aspects of speech, as explained in the linked document:

> A primeira sentença foi elaborada com a participação de todas as vogais da língua: em inglês “The blue spot in on the key again” e, na adaptação para o português “Érica tomou suco de pêra e amora”. A segunda enfatiza um início suave de sonorização com a emissão do /h/, sendo que optamos por usar início com a fricativa medial /s/, por questões fonológicas: em inglês “How hard did he hit him” e em português “Sonia sabe sambar sozinha”. A terceira sentença foi composta por segmentos totalmente sonoros: em inglês “We were away a year ago” e em português “Olha lá o avião azul”. A quarta sentença foi elaborada para eliciar a produção de ataques vocais bruscos: em inglês “We eat eggs every Easter” e em português “Agora é hora de acabar”. A quinta sentença foi produzida para testar a emissão de sons nasais: em, inglês “My mama makes lemon muffins” e em português “Minha mãe namorou um anjo”. Finalmente, a sexta sentença foi elaborada com sons plosivos surdos: em inglês “Peter will keep at the peak” e em português “Papai trouxe pipoca quente”.

**However**, they don't seem to be phonetically balanced, nor am I sure whether they contain all phonemes in Brazilian Portuguese (I haven't tried checking).

Comment: An avenue of research for this would be going to https://www.ieee.org and extracting the right keywords from the original English paper starting with the speech processing specialty. A "zero-mean" signal is a usual testing criteria for any carrier/encoder which is what the mentioned "Harvard sentences" seem to be about, a corpus that's complete in phonemes and has "zero-mean" in its sentences. I don't know of a specific corpus for your case but https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-linguistics/info accepts specialized resource requests and there are some experts on that site

Comment: This question might also find an expert audience at signal processing https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=harvard+sentences and it certainly would be on-topic at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @bad_coder-onstrike Thank you very much for the pointers! Do you know what the usual policy is for cross-posting in this StackExchange and linguistics, DSP, opendata? I know other pairs of closely related SE communities require e.g. enough time to pass after the question was first posted + cross-linking the questions on each site, but wanted to be sure if the same applies to this and the other three related SEs.

Comment: I think the [CETUC dataset](https://huggingface.co/lgris/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-open-brazilian-portuguese) might be what you want, it's described as: *"contains approximately 145 hours of Brazilian Portuguese speech distributed among 50 male and 50 female speakers, each pronouncing approximately 1,000 phonetically balanced sentences selected from the CETEN-Folha corpus."* Try googling for a transcription of the CETUC sentences.

Comment: @bad_coder-onstrike Oh this is perfect, thank you very much! I've download the dataset and copied the sentences from there together [here](https://github.com/topological-modular-forms/Phonetically-Balanced-Sentences-From-CETUC/blob/main/README.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CETUC dataset [mentioned](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-harvard-sentences-for-brazillian-portuguese?noredirect=1#comment25350_9768) by bad_coder makes use of 1000 phonetically balanced sentences from the CETEN-Folha corpus. These phrases come from the following paper:

> R. **Cirigliano**, C. **Monteiro**, F. **Barbosa**, F. **Resende Jr.**, L. R. **Couto**, J. A. **Moraes**, *Um Conjunto de 1000 Frases Foneticamente Balanceadas para o Português Brasileiro Obtido Utilizando a Abordagem de Algoritmos Genéticos*. Simpósio Brasileiro de Telecomunicações (SBrT), Campinas, Brasil, 2005, pp. 544–549. DOI: [10.14209/sbrt.2005.544](http://dx.doi.org/10.14209/sbrt.2005.544).

(English title; my translation: *A Collection of 1000 Phonetically Balanced Phrases for Brazillian Portuguese Compiled Through the Use of Genetic Algorithms*.)

The full dataset containing all sentences can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/lfelipesv/1000-sentences-thls-dataset/-/blob/master/sentences.txt?ref_type=heads). I've also made a backup copy [here](https://github.com/topological-modular-forms/1000-Phonetically-Balanced-Sentences-in-Brazilian-Portuguese).

Here are a few sample sentences from it:

1. Pesquisa é uma coisa que muda a toda hora.
2. No total, serão chamados vinte e seis mil candidatos.
3. O número de convocados por vaga é de doze candidatos.
4. Atualmente, esse abatimento é limitado a setenta por cento dos gastos.
5. Sandra Regina Machado: acho que ela enfim criou juízo.
6. Eles estão colocando armadilhas nas fazendas onde já ocorreram os ataques.
7. Dessas, somente umas trezentas e vinte foram inauguradas em território americano.
8. No total, sete mísseis foram disparados contra o encrave.
9. Em Florianópolis, foi registrado dois graus Celsius na manhã de domingo.
10. As situações ditas embaraçosas são resolvidas com os dados.

Comment: Very good answer, and you didn't have to turn it into a community wiki, in my opinion — acknowledging bad_coder's contribution, as you did, was enough.

Comment: @stafusa Hey I'm happy you liked the answer! Thank you very much for letting me know about your opinion on making it community wiki, I'm not very familiar with this particular SE, and it really helps to know how things work here!

Comment: The reason I decided to make it community wiki is one I've seen used in other SEs: it felt like one of those situations where the question has been essentially answered in the comments, and then posting a CW answer so that the question can go out of the unanswered queue and into the accepted questions one is usually nice. In this sense I feel like compiling the sentences from CETUC was quite quick, and finding the appropriate dataset was really most of the work in the end :)

Comment: (I still want to go through them in the git repository I posted and fix a few orthography issues in each one though, like capitalising proper names)

Comment: All I can say is I hope we can count with more contributions from you!

Answer (score 1):

Another dataset of phonetically balanced sentences can be found in the following work:

> **Izabel Christine Seara**, *Estudo Estatístico dos Fonemas do Português Falado na Capital de Santa Catarina para Elaboração de Frases Foneticamente Balanceadas*, MSc thesis, 1994. [Link](https://fonapli.paginas.ufsc.br/files/2020/04/Disserta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Izabel_SEara.pdf)

Here are the sentences:

**List 1**

1. A questão foi retomada no congresso.
2. Leila tem um lindo jardim.
3. O analfabetismo é a vergonha do país.
4. A casa foi vendida sem pressa.
5. Trabalhando com união rende muito mais.
6. Recebi nosso amigo para almoçar.
7. A justiça é a única vencedora.
8. Isso se resolverá de forma tranquila.
9. Os pesquisadores acreditam nessa teoria.
10. Sei que atingiremos o objetivo.

**List 2**

1. Nosso telefone está mudo.
2. Desculpe se te chamo de velho.
3. Queremos discutir o orçamento.
4. Ela não tem fome quando sai de casa.
5. Uma índia andava na floresta.
6. Zeca, corra bem rápido para casa.
7. Neste caso, dormirei tranquilo.
8. João deu dinheiro pro seu pai comprar um jogo.
9. Ainda faltam seis minutos.
10. Ela seguia discretamente.

**List 3**

1. Eu vi logo a índia Joana e o Léo.
2. João caminhou na praia calma.
3. Vi Zé fazer essas viagens seis vezes.
4. O atabaque do Tito é coberto com pele de gato.
5. Ele dorme num leito de palha.
6. Paira um ar de arara amarela no Rio.
7. Foi muito difícil entender a canção de natal.
8. Depois do almoço te encontro pro chá.
9. Esses são nossos timezinhos.
10. Procurei Maria em casa.

**List 4**

1. A pesca é proibida nesse canto.
2. Quero te ver bem quando ele voltar de lá.
3. Tenho muito orgulho de nossa gente.
4. O inspetor faz vistoria completa.
5. Ainda não se sabe o dia da prova.
6. Será muito difícil conseguir que eu coma.
7. A paixão dele é a natureza.
8. Você quer me dizer a data?.
9. Desculpe, mas me atrasei no casamento.
10. Faz um desvio em direção ao mar.

**List 5**

1. O velho tigre ainda aceita combate.
2. É hora do homem se humanizar mais.
3. Ela ficou na fazenda por uma hora.
4. Seu crime foi encoberto pelo capataz.
5. A escuridão do quarto assustou a criança.
6. Hoje, eu não pude fazer minha ginástica.
7. Comer quindim é sempre uma boa pedida.
8. Hoje irei precisar de você.
9. Sem ele o tempo flui num ritmo suave.
10. A sujeira lançada no rio contamina os peixes.

**List 6**

1. O jogo será transmitido à tarde.
2. É possível que ele já esteja fora de perigo.
3. A explicação pode ser encontrada na tese.
4. Meu voo tinha sido marcado para as cinco horas.
5. Daqui a pouco a gente via ao baile.
6. Estou certo que mereço a atenção dela.
7. Era um belo enfeite todo de palha.
8. O comércio daqui é bem tranquilo.
9. É a minha chance de esclarecer a notícia.
10. A visita transformou-se numa reunião.

**List 7**

1. O cenário da história é um subúrbio da cidade.
2. Eu tenho ótima razão para festeja.
3. A pequena nave medirá o campo magnético.
4. O prêmio será entregue na sessão solene.
5. A ação se passa numa cidade calma.
6. Ela e seu namorado chato saem do carro.
7. O adiantamento surpreendeu a mim e a todos.
8. A gente sempre colhe o que plantou.
9. Aqui é onde existe a flor mais interessante.
10. A corrida de inverno foi uma alegria.

**List 8**

1. Esse empreendimento terá grande sucesso.
2. A feira livre não funcionará amanhã.
3. Fumar é prejudicial à saúde e é feio.
4. Entre com seu velho código e o número da conta.
5. Reflita antes e discuta depois.
6. A aula dele é bastante charmosa.
7. Usar mais aditivo pode ser desastroso.
8. O clima não é mau em Calcutá.
9. A locomotiva vem com mais carga.
10. Ainda é uma boa temporada pro cinema.

**List 9**

1. Os maiores picos da Terra ficam debaixo da água.
2. A inauguração da vila é quarta ou quinta feira.
3. Vote se você tiver o título de eleitor.
4. Hoje é fundamental encontrar a razão da existência humana.
5. A temperatura é mais amena à noite.
6. Em muitas cidades a população está diminuindo.
7. Nunca se deve ficar em cima do morro.
8. Para as pessoas estranhas o panorama é desolador.
9. É bom te ver colhendo flores, menino!.
10. Eu finjo me banhar num lago ao amanhecer.

**List 10**

1. É de fundamental importância encontrar uma solução comum.
2. A previsão é de muito nevoeiro no Rio.
3. Os móveis virão as cinco da tarde.
4. O barraco pode desabar em algumas horas.
5. O candidato falou como se já estivesse eleito.
6. A ideia é falha, mas interessante.
7. O dia está bom para passear de navio.
8. Minha correspondência me espera em casa.
9. A saída para crise dele é o dialogo.
10. Finalmente São Pedro chamou o mau tempo.

**List 11**

1. Um casal de gatos come no telhado.
2. A cantora foi apresentar um grande sucesso.
3. Lá é um lugar ótimo para tomar uns chopinhos.
4. O musical consumiu quatro messe da vida da gente.
5. O baile começa após às nove horas.
6. Apesar desse resultado tomarei uma decisão.
7. A verdade não poupa nem as celebridades.
8. O frio deve diminuir ainda este ano.
9. O vão da plataforma é estreito.
10. Infelizmente não fui a ginástica.

**List 12**

1. Os meninos prenderam um filhote de tigre.
2. A bolsa de valores está em alta.
3. O congresso volta atrás em sua palavra.
4. A médica receitou que eles mudassem de clima.
5. Não é permitido fumar no interior do ônibus.
6. A garota foi presa naquela noite.
7. O prato do dia é couve no tempero.
8. Eu viajarei a Belém amanhã.
9. A balsa é o meio de transporte daqui.
10. A apresentação foi cancelada por causa da chuva.

**List 13**

1. O grêmio ganhou uma quadra de esportes.
2. Hoje irei à vila sem meu filho.
3. Essa chuva não ocorre mais todo ano.
4. Será bom que ele estudo o assunto.
5. O menu inclui um prato muito saboroso.
6. Podia dizer as horas por gentiliza?.
7. A casa é enfeitada com rosas.
8. A Terra é farta, mas não infinita.
9. O sinal emitido é captado pelos receptores.
10. A mensalidade aumentou mais que inflação.

**List 14**

1. O telejornal começa às dez da noite.
2. A cabine do telefone fica na próxima rua.
3. Defender a ecologia é manter a vida.
4. Nesse verão o calor é insuportável.
5. O jardim exige muito trabalho.
6. O pão que eu comprei era ótimo.
7. Meu pai se entenderá com o padre chato amanhã.
8. Durante o dia apague a luz.
9. A sociedade uruguaia tem que se mobilizar.
10. Nossas atitudes são calmas.

**List 15**

1. Dezenas de cabos eleitorais buscavam apoio.
2. Nunca uma vitória foi paga com tanto suor.
3. Nosso filho ama os animais.
4. Esse peixe é mais letal que algumas cobras.
5. O time continua lutando pelo sucesso.
6. Essa medida foi devidamente alterada.
7. O estilete é uma arma perigosa.
8. Me aguarde, quinta feira eu venho jantar em casa.
9. A mudança é lenta porém duradoura.
10. O clima não é mais seco no interior.

**List 16**

1. Sua sensibilidade mostrará o caminho.
2. A Amazônia é a reserva ecológica do globo.
3. O ministério mudou demais com a eleição.
4. Novas metas surgem na informática.
5. O capital de uma empresa depende de produção.
6. Se não fosse ela, tudo teria sido melhor.
7. A principal personagem no filme é uma gueixa.
8. Espere seu amigo em casa.
9. A juventude tinha que revolucionar a escola.
10. A cantora terá quatro meses para ensaiar seu canto.

**List 17**

1. Prazer em conhecê-los.
2. Elas traziam o equipamento.
3. O sol ilumina o planeta.
4. A correção do exame foi coerente.
5. O vidro é antigo, mas o armário, não.
6. O natal deve ser um dia alegra.
7. Trabalhei mais do que podia.
8. Hoje eu acordei calmo.
9. Esse canal parece bastante chato.
10. Nem parece que nós nascemos aqui.

**List 18**

1. Receba minha prima na festa.
2. Ela planejou um grande banquete cheio de gente.
3. No lado de cá do rio há uma boa sombra.
4. A maioria dos visitantes gosta deste momento.
5. Minha filha é especialista em música sacra.
6. A casa só tem um quarto.
7. A duração do simpósio é de cinco dias.
8. Ao contrário de nossa expectativa, tudo foi tranquilo.
9. A intenção é ter o apoio do governante.
10. A fila aumentou ao longo do dia.

**List 19**

1. À noite, a temperatura deve ir a zero.
2. A proposta foi inspecionada pela gerência.
3. Os quadros azuis mostram o cotidiano.
4. Já era tarde, quando ele me abordou.
5. O canário canta ao amanhecer.
6. A lojinha não fica na esquina.
7. Meu bom time se consagrou como o melhor.
8. O instituto deve servir a sua meta.
9. Ele não entende, nem quando se fala pausadamente.
10. Seu limite do cheque azul foi aumentado.

**List 20**

1. O termômetro indicava o calor.
2. O discurso de abertura tem que ser longo.
3. Eu precisei de tempo na conferência.
4. Zeca marcou a temporada de jogos.
5. Nada como um almoço ao ar livre.
6. Nossa filha é a primeira da classe.
7. Gostaria de chamar meu pai.
8. Não tive uma prova cansativa.
9. Ainda tenho cinco telefonemas pra dar.
10. Os hotéis do sudoeste são fantásticos.